# add query param value to a TYPO3 form

Tags: forms, typo3, typo3-9.x

Users come to a TYPO3 9.5 form page send by another page / link from same instance.

The URL of this ext-form page is e.g.:

`http://example.com/contact/?object=145&cHash=1af467e937c00ecbc88f78facf23696b`

How can I realize that the value (here "145") of the object is processed by the mail finisher? Thus gets sent to the receiving mail address?

I thought of a hidden field. But how can I enter the value into it?